# Why my Android setOnItemClickListener doesn't work?

Tags: android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android

I have problem in setting setOnItemClickListener. The following is my code. I've tested that setAdapter worked and the list and items were shown on the UI. When it came to setting setOnItemClickListener, it didn't work.

```
cool_simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items,
    R.layout.mylistitem, new String[] { "title", "link" }, new int[] {
            R.id.textView_title, R.id.textView_link });
cool_listView.setAdapter(cool_simpleAdapter);
Log.d("tag_1", "before setOnItemClickListener");
cool_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        Log.d("tag_setonItemClick", "in onItemClick");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
Log.d("tag_2", "after setOnItemClickListener");
```

I put the log to trace what happened:

```
Log.d("tag_1","before setOnItemClickListener");
```

and

```
Log.d("tag_2","after setOnItemClickListener");
```

were displayed but

```
Log.d("tag_setonItemClick","in onItemClick");
```

were not displayed. And I cannot click on the item, neither open the URL. I don't know how should I fix the problem.

Edit: add mylistitem.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_link"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14333069/1235555) and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Off-topic but I don't think that second `LinearLayout` is needed

Comment: I don't see any problem that you shared code and xml for setOnItemClickListener. May be you've set another setOnItemClickListener to your listView and overridden first one.

Comment: in fact using a single relative layout would be better

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the described behavior with the given code. For me, it works as expected; i.e., the log entry "tag_setonItemClick","in onItemClick" DOES appear upon clicking. Perhaps @aegean is correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in this condition your Button is focused so listiten setOnItemClickListener not working..so make them focusable false..
add this line in xml of  Button on

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before, that was because each item of listview had a Button.
to solve this just need to set  `android:focusable` of the button to `false`.
I hope this will help you

Comment: maybe you can try set TextView with android:focusable=false

Comment: Thanks @Patato for your help :)