# Android - Gridview with Custom BaseAdapter, create onclicklistener

Tags: android, gridview, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I have created a gridview which displays the letters of the alphabet. I populate the gridview with a string array using a custom BaseAdapter.

What i want to do is to be able to get the value (letter) of the clicked cell. In order to verify that it works, i have created a TextView and i want when the user clicks on an item (cell) to set the text of the TextView with the value of the selected cell

[image]

I have made an attempt which doesn't work. Here is my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myGridView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:numColumns="7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/feedback"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**cell.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/grid_item"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="05"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView text;
    private GridView gridView;
    private final String[] items = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);

        gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.myGridView);
        CustomGridAdapter gridAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                text.setText((String) (gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)));
                Log.i("ITEM_CLICKED", "" + (String) (gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**CustomGridAdapter**

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String[] items;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
        }
        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);
        button.setText(items[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

**Edit**: It seems that the gridView.setOnItemClickListener(...); is not called/executed. I have changed it to this in order to check it and i see nothing in the logcat.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("ON_ITEM_CLICK_LISTENER", "item clicked");
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is not working, can you elaborate? (Is your ItemClickListener not working)

Comment: Yes it isn't working. It seems that the gridView.setOnItemClickListener(...); is not called/executed.

Comment: Read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14333069/1235555) once.

Comment: i'd say your onItemClickListener should work if you add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your cell.xml root LinearLayout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem in your case is that the button is consuming the click and it doesn't get to GridView. I see two options:

1. The easy one: in `cell.xml` have these properties for your `Button`: `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"`
2. A grosso-modo: send the Activity as parameter to adapter and expose a public method from `MainActivity`. If you think of re-using the adapter, then send an abstract type of activity or an interface.

Something as:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView text;
    private GridView gridView;
    private final String[] items = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);

        gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.myGridView);
        CustomGridAdapter gridAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

    }

    public void itemClicked(int position) {
        text.setText(items[position]);
    }
}
```

and in your adapter:

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private MainActivity context;
    private String[] items;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity context, String[] items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
        }
        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);
        button.setText(items[position]);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                context.itemClicked(position);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Very nice. I like this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Actually for gridview setOnItemClickListener you are not doing anything wrong. It's the cell view that is creating the problem. Try changing cell-view button to a textview, it should work. Right now when you tap on an item in a gridview the item is not actually clicked because your cell-view button has it's own implementation of OnClickListener, and that is why setOnItemClickListener is not getting called.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. i have been busting my head for hours.

Comment: +1 from me ... however if you need to make the view act as a button - with pressed animations you need more. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTag() adnd getTag() which allow you to put/get any type of object.
So in the future, you will be able to pass anything (if you make the appropriate cast after)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
    }

    Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item);
    button.setText(items[position]);
    convertView.setTag(items[position]); 
    return convertView;
}
```

AND

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String str = (String) view.getTag();
            text.setText(str);
            Log.i("ITEM_CLICKED", "" + (String) (gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I just tried it. It doesn't work.