# How to call multiple ArrayList one by one in GridView Android

Tags: android, gridview

I have more then one ArrayList think that ArrayList1,ArrayList2,ArrayList3... In ArrayList1 have some images showing it in GridView android, when I click on images it should show ArrayList2 in that GridView only and ArrayList2 also having images. Same for ArrayList2 and ArrayList3. How to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your ArrayLists contain the same object type.

Create a new ArrayList, lets call it AdapterArrayList and use it as the main ArrayList for the Adapter. Now If you want to use ArrayList1, `clear()` elements from AdapterArrayList and then `addAll()` the ArrayList1. and of course `notifyDataSetChanged()` for the Adapter.

Do the same when you want to use ArrayList2 and ArrayList3.

[Edit]

For example:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
List<Image> mImagesList;

    public MyAdapter(List<Image> imagesList) {
        mImagesList = imagesList;
        ...
    }
}
```

And to use that adapter with the ArrayLists you have:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    List<Image> mainList = new ArrayList();
    List<Image> arrayList1 = new ArrayList();
    List<Image> arrayList2 = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mainList);
        myListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private void switchToList1() {
        mainList.clear();
        mainList.addAll(arrayList1);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void switchToList2() {
        mainList.clear();
        mainList.addAll(arrayList2);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AbdallalhAlaraby Give me a example or code something so that I can refer

Comment: @AbdallalhAlaraby how can I send id of selected grid element to the next grid?

Comment: This is a totally different question that should have it's own thread. anyway, you can define an `OnClickListener` inside the Adapter's `getView()` method. check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20191914/how-to-add-gridview-setonitemclicklistener)