# Tapping rows in Listview not working even w/ SetOnItemClicklistener in Android

Tags: android, listview

For some reason tapping a row in my list view doesn't seem to work even if I have the correct listener code. There are only textviews in the template of the lists. I know there's been discussion about assigning a listener when there is a button in the template of a list view. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332409/custom-listview-is-not-responding-to-the-click-event).

Here is my code:

ScheduleActivity:

```
public class ScheduleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String url;
    JSONObject data = null;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    Intent intent;
    String userId;
    int eventId;

    ListView scheduleListView;
    ScheduleAdapter scheduleAdapter;
    ArrayList<Schedule> scheduleList = new ArrayList<>();
    DBManager dbManager =  new DBManager(ScheduleActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.schedule_layout);
        Log.d("Test", ">>>ScheduleActivity<<<");
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        userId = extras.getString("userId");
        eventId = extras.getInt("eventId");

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.schedule_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Schedules");

        scheduleList = dbManager.getSchedules(eventId);

        scheduleAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(ScheduleActivity.this, scheduleList);
        scheduleListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scheduleListView);
        scheduleListView.setAdapter(scheduleAdapter);

        scheduleListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.w("Test", scheduleList.get(position).toString());
                intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, UpdateScheduleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userId", userId);
                intent.putExtra("eventId", eventId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        scheduleListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.w("Test", "Long click works");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.schedule_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.new_schedule) {
            intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, CreateScheduleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("eventId", eventId);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(id == R.id.rankings){
            Log.d("Test", "Rankings Activity clicked!");
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

ScheduleAdapter:

```
public class ScheduleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Schedule>{

    public ScheduleAdapter(Context context, List<Schedule> schedule) {
        super(context, R.layout.schedule_list_row, schedule);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater eventInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = eventInflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_list_row, parent, false);
        }

        Schedule singleSchedule = getItem(position);

        //TODO implement ViewHolder pattern
        TextView club1Code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.club1TextView);
        TextView club2Code= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.club2TextView);
        TextView club1Score = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.club1ScoreTextView);
        TextView club2Score = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.club2ScoreTextView);
        TextView club1SpiritScore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.club1SpiritScoreTextView);
        TextView club2SpiritScore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.club2SpiritScoreTextView);
        TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
        TextView day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);

        club1Code.setText(singleSchedule.getClub1Id());
        club2Code.setText(singleSchedule.getClub2Id());
        day.setText("Day " + singleSchedule.getDay());
        time.setText(singleSchedule.getStartTime() + " - " + singleSchedule.getEndTime());
        club1Score.setText(Integer.toString(singleSchedule.getClub1Score()));
        club2Score.setText(Integer.toString(singleSchedule.getClub2Score()));
        club1SpiritScore.setText(Integer.toString(singleSchedule.getClub1SpiritScore()));
        club2SpiritScore.setText(Integer.toString(singleSchedule.getClub2SpiritScore()));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kennanseno.ultimate_scoreboard_app.Activity.ScheduleActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/schedule_toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:title="@string/event_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scheduleListView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/schedule_toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Row Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/club1_name_text"
        android:id="@+id/club1TextView"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:layout_above="@+id/club1SpiritScoreTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/club2_name_text"
        android:id="@+id/club2TextView"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dayTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/score_divider"
        android:id="@+id/score_divider"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/club1_score_text"
        android:id="@+id/club1ScoreTextView"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/score_divider"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/club2_score_text"
        android:id="@+id/club2ScoreTextView"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/score_divider"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/start_time_text"
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dayTextView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/club2ScoreTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club1ScoreTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/club1_spirit_score_text"
        android:id="@+id/club1SpiritScoreTextView"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/club2SpiritScoreTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club1TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/club2_spirit_score_text"
        android:id="@+id/club2SpiritScoreTextView"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/club2TextView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/club2TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/schedule_day_text"
        android:id="@+id/dayTextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/club2ScoreTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/club1ScoreTextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Row Template xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

causing issue because `RelativeLayout` is clickable with `match_parent` height-width.

if you want to get click event for whole row then no need to make parent layout clickable just set `setOnItemClickListener` to ListView otherwise you need to set `onClickListener` for `RelativeLayout` in `ScheduleAdapter` class.